# Spring Boot - How to create manually a bean and pass it to a hash map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

Want put a class in a HashMap. For that I have created a Bean with @Service. This is it:

```
@Service
public class ServiceManagerImpl implements ServiceManager {

@Override
 public void registerService() {
    // registerService will put this in the HashMap!
    dispatcher.registerService("serviceList", getServiceListImpl());
 }

 @Bean
 public BusinessService getServiceListImpl() {
    return new ServiceListManager();
 }
}
```

Is this the right way to make something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Move your bean definition from a class annotated with @Service to a configuration class annotated with @Configuration (or at least move to your main class which has @SpringBootApplication annotation, if you have). Then Autowire that bean here in the Service class. `

> @Autowired BusinessService businessService

take a look here [Where to put @Bean in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146019/where-to-put-bean-in-spring-boot?rq=1)

Comment: Changing @ Service to @ Configuration throws a _BeanCreatinException_. What do you mean with _move to the main class_ ? Not clear for me.

Comment: Which is your application entry point? where is your main method?
take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146019/where-to-put-bean-in-spring-boot?rq=1

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I know, what you mean... And what I have to do, when I want to load Beans in the Application Context dynamically? Then a configuration file would not work.

Comment: Then Autowire that bean here in the Service class. 

`@Autowired BusinessService businessService`