# How to use class which is not a dependency in my spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring project I can defined bean in XML like this:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

even my project does not contain `weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl`  class. When I deploy my application to wls server everything works fine just STS is complaining that it doesn't know this class. How I can convert this code to spring-boot application and define this factory in some java class ?

Answer (score 0):

In a configuration class (has `@Configuration` above class definition) create a method as a factory for your `MessageFactoryImpl` and use `@Bean` above it. Defining a bean in spring boot is like the old java configuration.

See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146019/where-to-put-bean-in-spring-boot) , It will help

Comment: when I use weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl() in java class I can not compile it

Answer (score 0):

`weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl` is an implementation class which exists already in WebLogic server library jars.

To do that using `@Bean`, use `@ConditionOnClass`

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConditionalOnClass(weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl.class)
public SoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    return new weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl();
}
```

Comment: yes but I have no dependency on wls in my project so when I add this I can not compile it

Comment: You add the jar dependency and make it scope as `compileOnly` (in Gradle)

Comment: I am not sure if there is maven dependency for wls jar

Comment: Ya it use [maven.oracle.com repository](https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/weblogic-server-and-the-oracle-maven-repository), the jar is `weblogic:com.bea.core.weblogic.saaj` I think. Btw, you can find the jar in your weblogic server (weblogic.jar or something similar).